Add trend lines in the legend using ggplot2
I would like to add trend lines (blue dashed, black dashed and red dashed ) keeping the time series point line legend separate.
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
          2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
          2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)

temp <- c(05, 08, 07, 05, 10, 13, 08, 
          10, 12, 11, 08, 14, 17, 10, 
          20, 18, 23, 25, 21, 28, 30)

type <- c("min","min","min","min","min","min","min",
          "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean",
          "max","max","max","max","max","max","max")

type <- as.factor(type)

series <- data.frame(year = year, temp = temp, type = type)


ggplot(series, aes(x = year, y = temp,  group = type)) + geom_line(aes(color = type)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = type)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = type, color = type ), formula = 'y ~ x' , method=lm, se = F, linetype = "dashed", show.legend = T) + 
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("blue","black", "red") ) + 
  xlim(2000,2006) +
  labs(x = "Year", 
       y = TeX("Temperatura"),
       colour = "Legend")


I'm not sure I understand. Exactly what do you want to change? Are you trying to create two separate legends for color?

I am trying to add the trend lines in the legend. Time series legend and trend line legend separate

I got to your desired output by changeing geom_point(aes(color = type)) + to geom_point(aes(shape = type)) + like so
ggplot(series, aes(x = year, y = temp,  group = type)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = type)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = type)) + # <-------------
  geom_smooth(aes(group = type, color = type ), formula = 'y ~ x' , method=lm, se = F, linetype = "dashed", show.legend = T) + 
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("blue","black", "red") ) + 
  xlim(2000,2006) +
  labs(x = "Year", 
       y = latex2exp::TeX("Temperatura"),
       colour = "Legend")



An easy way to get a separate legend for your trend lines would be to use the ggnewscale package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic, i.e. in your case you want two separate legends for the color aestethic:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(series, aes(x = year, y = temp, group = type)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = type)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = type)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("blue", "black", "red"),
    name = "Legend"
  ) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = type, color = type),
    formula = "y ~ x", method = lm, se = FALSE,
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("blue", "black", "red"),
    name = "Trend"
  ) +
  xlim(2000, 2006) +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Temperatura"
  )


